# Passing url path into React from Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony 5 and the Vich uploader bundle for uploading images, and I have a separate React app within the project that handles the images. The image directory and path created by Vich Uploader config and can be access within the Symfony environment. But I don't know how to pass that url path into my React app.

My React app is connected using the Symfony document with a twig template.

show_image.twig.html

```
<div id="root"></div>

{% block javascripts %
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

app.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Can I get the path into my React app without hardcoding them in?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pass data in your front is to store the data in a var in your twig like this:

```
<div id="root"></div>

{% block javascripts %
    <script>
        var imagePath = '{{ image_path }}';
    </script>
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app') }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi the code works but I also got a syntax error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'imagePath' has already been declared"

Comment: The imagePath variable I declared in my example is in the global scope. I guess you try to redefine somewhere in your react code an other variable with the name imagePath